# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment in a swap with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Ok I have searched around and nothing can explain what this produce "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment" in the 2nd and 3nd line. Of course I have tried some alternative statements but nothing works and I do not get it why compiler doesnt accept it. arr is a array of pointers and this is a simple swap.

```
player tmp = *(arr+i);
arr+i = (*(arr+i+1));
(arr+i+1) = &tmp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [] syntax may make it easier:

```
player tmp = arr[i];
arr[i]     = arr[i+1];
arr[i+1]   = tmp;
```

If you insist on the *(arr+i) syntax:

```
player tmp = *(arr+i);
*(arr+i)   = *(arr+i+1);
*(arr+i+1) = tmp;
```

Comment: It works with the second syntax. Probably works with the first one as well. But I thought I had tried this one. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `arr+1` is not an lvalue.  That means it's not something you can assign to.  Did you mean to have a `*` somewhere?